# How to fix 'Possible SQL injection' in raw SQL when scanning with Brakeman

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, brakeman

I'm using ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute to insert data to database. After running brakeman report I get this warning : "Possible SQL injection"

```rb
sql = "INSERT INTO `students` (`student_id`,`level') VALUES (1, #{Student.get_level_name(1)});"
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute sql
```

And tried a couple of other stuff which didn't work not even worth mentioning. Does anybody have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Always use *prepared statements*. Their exact usage depends on the database used.

Comment: Thanks @Erlkoenig, Do you have any idea about inserting a bunch of records, something like: sql = "INSERT INTO `students` (`student_id`,`level') VALUES (1, #{Student.get_level_name(1)}),(2, #{Student.get_level_name(1)})", It seem like Brakeman alway catches Student.get_level_name(1) method.

Comment: Also, I have wrapped Student.get_level_name(1) method with ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote method, but nothing's changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the interpolation you're doing to create the statement.

```
".. (1, #{Student.get_level_name(1)});"
```

Despite Brakeman doesn't know where that value is coming from if you pass any value there, you're vulnerable to SQLi.

That's why you should be using ActiveRecord to handle database inserts. It allows you to pass the values for the records and it deals with the bindings and sanitization:

```
INSERT INTO "students" ("student_id", "created_at", "updated_at")
VALUES ($1, $2, $3)
RETURNING "id"
[["student_id", "1"], ["created_at", "2019-09-27 07:06:57.198752"], ["updated_at", "2019-09-27 07:06:57.198752"]]
```

There you can see `($1, $2, $3)` correspondingly as the "student_id", "created_at", "updated_at" values, which aren't passed in RAW form to your query (timestamps are generated automatically if you added them).

So, for the insert:

```
Student.create(student_id: 1, level: Student.get_level_name(1))
```

Comment: Thank Sebastian Palma, cuz I want to insert a set of records by 1 SQL query,  with interpolation parameter is a method or ActiveRecord::Relation, but it seems like Brakeman not accept this way: sql = "INSERT INTO students (student_id,`level') VALUES (1, #{Student.get_level_name(1)}),(2, #{Student.get_level_name(1)})

Comment: What Rails version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Rails 4.2.10, ruby 2.5.1p57

Comment: Rails 6 has added support for bulk import. Older versions can use the [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) gem.

Comment: I have used activerecord-import as a substitution solution. Again, thank Sebastian

Comment: Nice! Glad to help and happy coding ;)